# Is it possible to you MNIST model for thousands of classifications?

Tags: python, classification, mnist

I am very new to ML and I am trying to create a CNN which basically does exactly the same thing as MNIST handwritten digit recognition model, but instead of 10 classifications I'd like to use over 2000. is such thing possible? I tried this:

```
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2006, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

Training does complete, however I get zero loss and zero accuracy. What am I doing wrong? (besides from not studying ML in depth) Sorry for the noobnes. Any direction or help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you are also trying to recognize handwritten digits? Or are your data different?

Comment: slightly different, It consists of a few thousand symbols (letters, digits, random characters), 25 x 25px with 3000 sample images for each one of them.